# How to use Notification Hub on UWP?

Tags: c#, azure, notifications, win-universal-app, azure-notificationhub

Why cannot I install Microsoft Azure Notification Hub library and (or) Microsoft Azure Service Bus through NuGet into Universal Windows app project? In Windows 8.1/Phone 8.1 apps all works perfectly, not like in Windows 10.

Answer (score 2):

As of July 2016 Notification Hubs SDK is not available for UWP. The product team is aware of it and working on providing it.

At the moment, there are two ways to workaround it:

- Use `WindowsAzure.Messaging.Managed` Nuget package as described in [Getting started with Notification Hubs for Windows Universal Platform Apps](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/notification-hubs-windows-store-dotnet-get-started-wns-push-notification/)
- Use [REST API](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn223264.aspx).

@quillaur, certain Hubs SDKs are [open sourced](https://github.com/Azure/azure-notificationhubs). But, unfortunately, not Windows ones at the moment.

Comment: WindowsAzure.Messaging.Managed worked for my UWP app, able to receive notifications. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean that notification
I'm not ready to know you want to do and
I know that you can use ms cloud to push info

```
[DataContract]
public clas OAuthToken
{
    [DataMember(Name="access_token")]
    public string AccessToken{set;get;}
    [DataMember(Name="token_type)]
    public string TokenType{set;get;}
```

}

And win10 UWP may download the library in GitHub but I can't find it now.

Comment: I use Azure Notification Hub and scheduled push notifications from it. I also want to use Microsoft.Azure.NotificationHubs for my app but it can't be installed in UWP project. Before in Win8.1 project all works. Why so?

Comment: I don't know why it can't be installed in UWP but I think you can get code from github and you use the code to make UWP.

Comment: Unfortunately, Microsoft Azure Notification Hub library isn't open source.